# C# wpf - Adding to xaml file during execution

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

This is what my main program GUI will look like, what I am attempting to do, is to create a reminder application in C# using wpf.

[image]

I am going to use a scroll viewer which is going to be displaying the data to the user, namely the reminders they currently have.

Each time the user adds a reminder, it will add this:

[image]

What I am wanting to do is that, when ever the user add's a new reminder, there will be a new set of data added to the scrollviewer.

What would be the best way of achieving this?

Am I able to hold the xaml data and add it during execution?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do can be accomplished not by dynamic Xaml, but by the use of a `templated` control which can accept dynamic data. For example you wouldn't consider using a listbox for your labels because you are not showing the data in a list right?

But a listbox is just a conveyor belt for what you want to achive. Say you want more than a label, how about three labels. Via binding to a proper structure you can get what is needed.

Here is an example

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding myReminders }">
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
       <StackPanel>
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ReminderName}" />
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Description}"/>
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Priority}"/>
       </StackPanel>
     </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
 </ListBox>
```

Once that is bound to a list of my reminder data objects (which the list can dynamically change), we have the ability to show the reminders in *any* format we want. One just uses the above to style it appropriately. (Check out WPF's [Templating Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for a great example).

The use of templates is done in other controls, so if the listbox is not to your liking, look into other templated controls.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So, It will create a new Listbox for every item in MyReminders with that template right ?

Comment: @user2469515 yes, put your items into an `ObservableCollection` so when an item is added, it notifies the binder that it has changed. Or if not in an observable collection, simply re-binding to a list will achieve the same effect.

Comment: @user2469515 I have a blog article [Xaml: ViewModel Main Page Instantiation and Loading Strategy for Easier Binding](http://omegacoder.com/?p=1017) which gives a quick MVVM example and binding if you are new to MVVM.